# How to produce those curves in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing

I would like to reproduce the curves as shown in the picture below (taken from [here](http://math.richardgriffon.me/thesis/Griffon_thesis.pdf)):

[image]

I don't know if this was produced via LaTeX, but possibly TikZ or something similar was used. I guess that a "foreach" loop could have been used, which would also allow to change the color automatically. **But how to reproduce this brush-painting style?**

The curves look like elliptic curves, with equations of the form

> $y^2 + a_1 xy + a_3 y = x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_4 x + a_6$ with the $a_i$ being real numbers.

Would you have any hints/ideas?

Here is a close-up:
[image]

Comment: I'm just thinking: maybe  it was produced with SAGE? (See https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/explicit_methods_in_number_theory/elliptic_curves.html#bryan-birch-s-birthday-card)

Comment: Here is an idea: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614526/square-root-of-a-function-misbehaves-near-the-x-axis

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/475141/47927 maybe